# Ngx-Quill lists are not showing correctly

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

im using ngx-quill 16.2.1 in angular 13 project.
When I create a list, it is displayed correctly and the value is saved in the database.

[List in ngx quill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZt3D.png)

But when im recovering value of database and i pass to ngx quill, list disappears. Passing value to a div with [innerHTML] it works so is not a value problem.
If i inspect the dom the value of components its a p tag without the list tags ul and li

[Recovered value in ngx quill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7be9Q.png)

However, this does not happen with bold, italic, hyperlink etc. I believe I have all the necessary css.

[Css imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tenhj.png)

Does anyone know what might be going on? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code as text not an images.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using ngx-quill within the angular material tabs. I found an issue in the ngx-quill repo where a user suggest to lazy load the tab content like this (which solved the problem for me):

```
<mat-tab>
    <ng-template matTabContent>
        <quill-editor></quill-editor>
    </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

Source: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/404#issuecomment-525235789

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem as yours. Solved it by formatting as JSON:

```
<quill-editor
    [format]="'json'"
>
</quill-editor>
```